# Build a Python UDP server

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have multiple clients which will send big data to a server. And I need build my server.

I want to use UDP as my server in python. There a key:

- The server need know the data received is from where eg: client use
  udp://ip:port/data?client=test as data put localtion. server know
  this data is from `test` client

How I should build my server? Somebody can give advitise?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication#Receiving

But:
*If considering extending this example for e.g. file transfers, keep in mind that UDP is not reliable. So you'll have to handle packets getting lost and packets arriving out of order. In effect, to get something reliable you'll need to implement something similar to TCP on top of UDP, and you might want to consider using TCP instead.*

Comment: yeah, I can build a udp server through this page. But it can not solve my problem. Thank you.